# Fifa 13 online pass

Tags: fifa-13

When I try to go online with FIFA it always gives me this message

> we're sorry but you are not permitted to register the online pass

I tried to find it in the PSN STORE to try to redownload it but I couldn't find it.
I never registered my online pass before and never tried to play online because of the message they all way give me when i try to play online.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you, by chance, buy this game used?

Comment: no it was sealed.. it came with the PS as a gift

Comment: @Fluttershy any idea?

Comment: Somehow, I suspect EA's key authentication has gone a little loopy.

Comment: @Harout  With it being a new copy, I have nothing. =(

Comment: I vaguely remember having the same problem on my 360. I am not sure how PSN works, but on Xbox 360 I had to redeem the code like I would be redeeming DLC for any other game. Outside of the game in a seperte menu. Then you can download the DLC and all is well. Try putting in the code where you'd normally get DLC?

Answer (score 2):

Contact EA

There are also less reputable online outlets who will re-seal used games, so there is a chance the code has been used, so returning the game for an exchange is another option.